# If i've scrambled an array, `a`, to get an array `b`, how can I get an array of indices, '`i` such that `b[i] == a`?

Tags: python, matlab, sorting

I know in both MATLAB and numpy in Python, you can return the indices that were used to sort an array `a` to get a sorted array, `b`. I'm asking for the general algorithm implementation behind returning these indices when you're not sorting, but simply scrambling. This must be a known algorithm, but I didn't know what to look for when searching for this.

E.g. say I have an array `a == [7,6,8,9]`, and I set `b=a[3,4,2,1]` so `b == [8,9,6,7]`. Given this information, what is the most efficient code that would take me back from `b` to `a` (i.e. code that would yield the array `i = [4,3,1,2]`, because `b[i] == a`). This should be applicable to an array of any size. I'm asking for an explanation and code in either MATLAB or Python, thanks!

Comment: `[b.index(i) for i in a] ` will work for this simple case. But if can't guarantee unique values then `index` is just going to return the first index it finds.

Answer (score 3):

In Matlab, just use the second output of [`sort`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html):

```
ind = [3,4,2,1];
[~, result] = sort(ind);
```

Or, as suggested by @CrisLuengo, you can do it just with indexing:

```
result(ind) = 1:numel(ind);
```

Either of the above gives

```
result =
     4     3     1     2
```

Comment: this is exactly what I wasn't looking for, because as I stated, I'm looking for a general case that can be applied when "scrambling" an array, not just sorting in ascending or descending order

Comment: I don't understand what you want then. My code gives the desired result for your example. Please post another example where my code fails so I can see what you want

Comment: Oh, I see what you are doing now! I totally missed it on first read. Yes, these would be the same thing. I think OP also misunderstood what you are doing. :)

Comment: @CrisLuengo Your version has to be faster. I've added it

Comment: That is the fix of my broken version. It is what I was thinking, but not what I wrote. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Python Code** :

```
a = [7, 6, 8, 9, 8]

b = [8, 8, 9, 7, 6]

i = []
for x in a:
    index = b.index(x)
    i.append(index)

    # for duplicates
    b[index] = -1

print(i)
```

**Output :**

```
[3, 4, 0, 2, 1]
```